# how to receive parameters in a new google apps page

Tags: google-apps-script

From my Index.html page, I take parameters to my Trabajo.html page through the following link:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/************/exec?page=Trabajos&item=23
```

but I don't know how to receive the variable "item" on my page "Trabajo.html"

Codigo.html

```
function getScriptUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}
```

Index.Html

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">

 <html>
    <head>
      <base target="_top">
   </head>
<body>
   <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Trabajos&item=23' target="_blank"> <input type='button' name='button' value='Trabajos.html'></a>
</body>
 </html>
```

Trabajos.html

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
       <base target="_top">
   </head>
   <body>
      <br><br>
      //Here I want to show the value of the item, and also in a <script>
      <input type='text' value='<?=item?>' >
      <br><br>
      <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Index'> <input type='button' name='button' value='Index.html'></a>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I don't know how to receive the item variable, how could I do it if my code is like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: is distinct in javascript that in google apps, dont it's the same

Comment: Please add your doGet too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use templates

```
function doGet() {
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Trabajos');
  htmlTemplate.item = 'Set the item here';
  return htmlTemplate.evaluate();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't ask what you answer ... I'll edit my question so that I understand the code I have

Comment: I get this error--> "ReferenceError: item" no está definido. (línea 25, archivo "Código", proyecto "Inci")"

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you creating a Google [Web-App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

- A Google Web App usually consists of a `Code.gs` (not `Code.html`) file  and one `.html` file which will be returned when the Web App url is opened.
- A crucial part of a Web App is a [doGet(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) function within which the html file to call will be returned.
- In your case, you have **two** `.html` files that you want to open with the same Web App url.
- In this case you need to make a case differentiation within the `doGet()` function to create a different html template in function of `item`
- To pass `item` from the url   `https://script.google.com/macros/s/************/exec?page=Trabajos&item=23`
  to the `.html` file, you need to retrieve it within the `doGet()` function as a `e.parameter` and pass it to the `htmlTemplate`.

**Sample:**

> Code.gs

```
function doGet(e){
   var item=e.parameter.item;  
  if(item==23){
     var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Trabajos');
         htmlTemplate.item = item;
  }else if(item==24){
    ...
  }
  }else if(!item){
     var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  }
  ...
  return htmlTemplate.evaluate();
}


function getScriptUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}
```

`Index.html` and `Trabajos.html` can stay for this sample as they are.